# Variable substitution in a plist - can I define a value once and reuse it in a manually maintained plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, inheritance, plist

I have a manually maintained property list which defines an array of objects of the same type. The objects have many properties one of which is a regular expression string. Some of the objects share a common regular expression, my issue is that I have to maintain the same regex in multiple places in the file and this is error prone.

Is there any way to define the regular expression once and use variable replacement to make sure it's set on the right objects in the plist?

Answer (score 2):

How about instead of having one property and having to determine when to make a substitution, you have two properties. One will be `"regex"`, which you are currently using, the other will be a `"namedRegex"`. In another section of your plist, you can define all the named regular expression.

```
"namedRegexes" = {
  "regex1" = ".*";
  "regex2" = "[0-9]*";
  …
}
…
"objects" = {
    "object1" = {
        "regex" = "[A-Z]*";
        …
    };
    "object2" = {
        "namedRegex" = "regex1";
        …
    }
    …
}
```

At runtime, you will need to look for a regex, if one does not exist, then look for a namedRegex. If there is a namedRegex, then lookup that name in namedRegexes.